# IOS-Saving my objects into NSMutableDictionary as id's

Tags: ios, save, nsmutabledictionary

I want to save things into NSMutableDictionary with my own object as the key

for that i implemented the NSCopying protocol for my object, and all of the elements that it uses
last night, it did save the objects, this morning, when i ran the exact same code, it did not save it anymore.

why is that ?

these are my NSCopying methods :

```
    - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    Player *player = [[[self class]allocWithZone:zone]init];
    if(player){
    player->name = [name copyWithZone:zone];
    player->deck = [deck copyWithZone:zone];
    }
    return player;
}
-(id)copy{
    Player *player = [[[self class]alloc]init];
    if(player){
    player->name = [name copy];
    player->deck = [deck copy];
    }
    return player;
}

 -(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object{
    if(![object isKindOfClass:[Player class]]){
        return NO;
    }
    Player *player = (Player *)object;
    return [self.name isEqualToString:[player name]];
}

   -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    DeckOfCards *deckOfCards = [[[self class]allocWithZone:zone]init];
    if(deckOfCards){
    deckOfCards->deck = [deck copyWithZone:zone];
    }
    return deckOfCards;
}
-(id)copy{
    DeckOfCards *deckOfCards = [[[self class]alloc]init];
    if(deckOfCards){
    deckOfCards->deck = [deck copy];
    }
    return deckOfCards;
}
```

this is how i want to use the objects: 
in viewDidLoad

```
CGPoint  player1CardOrigin = CGPointMake(20, 160);
CGPoint  player2CardOrigin = CGPointMake(180, 160);

[origins setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:player1CardOrigin] forKey:player1];
[origins setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:player2CardOrigin] forKey:player2];
```

somewhere later in the code

```
Player *player = [game playerToMove];
CGPoint origin = [[origins objectForKey:player]CGPointValue];
```

at this point, origin is already 0,0 again, instead of the right value

what i dont understand is, why yesterday it worked, and today it doesnt?
what am i doing wrong ?

further inspection showed:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    Player *player1 = [Player playerWithName:[self getNameFromTextField:tfPlayer1]];
    Player *player2 = [Player playerWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[self getNameFromTextField:tfPlayer2]]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:@"player1" forKey:player1];
    [dict setObject:@"player2" forKey:player2];
    NSLog(@"dict: %@",dict);
}
```

clicking on said button multiple times,produces the following output:

```
2013-06-29 10:06:10.165 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "2 \n(0)" = (null);
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
}
2013-06-29 10:06:13.612 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
    "2 \n(0)" = player2;
}
2013-06-29 10:06:19.407 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
    "2 \n(0)" = player2;
}
2013-06-29 10:06:20.798 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
    "2 \n(0)" = (null);
}
2013-06-29 10:06:21.780 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "2 \n(0)" = (null);
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
}
2013-06-29 10:06:22.620 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "2 \n(0)" = player2;
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
}
2013-06-29 10:06:23.402 CardWarGame[3109:c07] dict: {
    "2 \n(0)" = (null);
    "1\n(0)" = player1;
}
```

which seems to me that sometimes it fails to save the object for the given key...?
what can i do to fix it, help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should have also overided this method:

```
-(NSUInteger)hash{
    NSLog(@"player hash");
    return [[self name]hash];
}
```

and then it works everytime